# Zend framework Class 'Model_DbTable_indexview' not found in <Directory>

Tags: php, zend-framework, fatal-error, zend-db-table

I just installed a script i purchased and i'm facing issues with the file not found.  I checked the function and `Model_DbTable_indexview` do exist in the model folder. Is there anywhere that i should be looking at ? Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This function is used to get the page url

```
*/ function curPageURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http'; 

    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
        $pageURL .= "s";

    $pageURL .= "://"; 

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    }
    else
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    } 
    return $pageURL;
}
```

`Fatal error: Class 'Model_DbTable_indexview' not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/heroku/htdocs/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 12`

Comment: make sure your resource autoloader is configured correctly.

Comment: Hi, okay i will research on what that is, new to Zend, using Codeigniter previously. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not using 'application' namespace also not following ZF class naming convention , so do this rename your class to

```
Application_Model_DbTable_IndexView
```

And change file name ot

```
IndexView.php
```

Comment: The error will still be there. Suspecting that the model isnt loaded? Is that how Zend work?

Comment: you have still not changes the indexView to IndexView , Also make sure the file is located at /opt/bitnami/apps/heroku/htdocs/application/models/DbTable/IndexView.php

Comment: since you are on *nix system its important to hv every file/folder is in correct letter case . for e.x it shd be  DbTable not dbtable .

Comment: I fixed the CAPS, still the same set of error. Thanks for your help here :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the class file iven exists in:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/heroku/htdocs/application/models/dbtable/indexview
```

Answer (score 1):

Under default settings for autoloader and `appnamespace`, the class

```
Application_Model_DbTable_SomeModel
```

should reside in the file

```
application/models/DbTable/SomeModel.php
```

In particular, note the mixed-case for `DbTable` in both the classname and the path, as well the plural `models` in the path.

You need to confirm (including upper/lowercase) all of the following:

1. Class name: `Application_Model_DbTable_SomeModel`
2. File and path : `application/models/DbTable/SomeModel.php`

Then the autoloader will allow you to instantiate (in a controller, say) by using:

```
$model = new Application_Model_SomeModel();
```